# prepared statements node-postgresql error with null result

Tags: node.js, postgresql, prepared-statement, node-postgres

i am new in node.js and postgresql. am allready connected with postgres db and execute some test code. after am going to use prepared statements.am create a sample login script. if user exist it return username else return message "invalid username or password". if username and password is correct,it return username. but no data will present , then could not return message. my openion is that , the control will crashed after executing cliend.end() function.

this is my code

```
UserLogin.get = function(userName, callBack) {
    pg.connect(pgConString, function(err, client, done) {
        if (err) {
            callBack("DB connection failed. " + err, null);
            return;
        }
        var selectQuery="SELECT * from  "  + TABLE + " WHERE userName=($1)";
        var query=client.query({
                text:selectQuery,
                values:[userName],
                name:"selectQuery"});

                query.on("error", function (error) {
                 callBack("DB fetch failed. Error Message: " + err, null);});

                query.on('row', function(row) {
                callBack(null, row);});

                query.on("end", function (result) {
                client.end();
                return;
                 });
            });     
}
```

> if row is empty, not return to callback. if row_result is not empty, its working fine.. How...????  any idea...???

Comment: try close instead of end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code

```
query.on('row', function(row) {
  callBack(null, row);
});
```

means that the callback will be called everytime the query fetches 1 row from the database. In the case when the query has 0 results, the callback will never be called.

Comment: i need to retrun all rows.

Comment: if any ideas to return all rows in a single callback

Comment: you should use this form of client.query (with callback supplied)  https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/wiki/Client#parameterized-query-with-optional-callback-supplied - this will give you all rows in the result.

Answer (score 2):

finally i got the answer. thanks for u r supports

```
UserLogin.get = function(userName, callBack) {
    pg.connect(pgConString, function(err, client, done) {
        if (err) {
            callBack("DB connection failed. " + err, null);
            return;
        }
        var selectQuery="SELECT * from  "  + TABLE + " WHERE userName=($1)";
       var query=client.query({
            text:selectQuery,
            values:[loginId],
            name:"selectQuery"});

            query.on("error", function (error) {
             callBack("DB fetch failed. Error Message: " + err, null);return;});

            query.on('row', function(row,result) {
            result.addRow(row);
            });

            query.on('end', function (result) {
            callBack(null,result.rows);
            client.end();
            return;
             });
        });     
}
```

in my old code, callback will be called everytime the query fetches 1 row from the database. am just changed the logic

Comment: For simpler usage, check out [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) ;)

Comment: we are using pg module. becasue pg-promise module could not support all postgres versions.

Comment: That's not possible, because `pg-promise` uses `pg` module.